# Считать и вывести строку

Tags: rust

Не могу сделать простое считывание из стандартного входного потока (`stdin`) и вывод считанного (в `stdout`) через `println!`
Смотрю статьи от IBM, похоже они устарели, код не работает.. Этот код я кое-как сделал по справке, но работает некорректно.

```
fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    println!("What is your name?");
    let mut buff = String::new();
    match stdin.read_line(&mut buff) {
        Ok(n) => println!("Hello, {}!", n),
        Err(err) => println!("Error: {}", err)
    }

    println!("Loop cycle, close cmd!");

    loop {

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
P.S. — Ещё один маленький вопрос: как можно разобрать enum в переменную? Ну вот тот же Result, без match никак? Из интереса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    println!("What is your name?");
    let mut buff = String::new();
    match stdin.read_line(&mut buff) {
        Ok(_) => println!("Hello, {}!", buff),
        Err(err) => println!("Error: {}", err)
    }

    println!("Loop cycle, close cmd!");

    loop {

    }
}
```

Метод [Stdin::read_line()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line) возвращает `Result<usize, io::Error>`, то есть в `Ok` число прочитанных байт. Прочитанная строка находится в `buff` (иначе зачем его передавали вообще по мутабельной ссылке?).

Разобрать enum можно с помощью любого паттерн матчинга, учитывающего все варианты так или иначе. Это `match`, `if let`, `while let`. Просто через `let Ok(_) = ...` нельзя, потому что не понятно что делать, если выбран любой другой вариант (например `Err`).

В данном случае можно было использовать `if let`:

```
if let Ok(_) = stdin.read_line(&mut buff) {
    println!("Hello, {}!", buff);
} else {
    println!("Some error :-(");
}
```

Но при таком варианте содержимое `Err` не будет доступно.

В случае `Result` и `Option` ещё можно использовать семейство `unwrap*` методов: `unwrap()` (паникует, если ошибочный/пустой вариант), `unwrap_or()` (если ошибочный вариант возвращает данное значение), `unwrap_or_else()` (при ошибочном варианте вызывает замыкание и возвращает то, что оно вычислит), `expect()` (как `unwrap()` но с кастомным сообщением об ошибке).

Comment: Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, пометьте, пожалуйста, ответ как принятый, чтобы не смущать народ, который ищет неотвеченные вопросы.